# How to calculate corr from a dataframe with non-numeric columns

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have these data set as shown below:

[image]

which belong to Pokemon dataset
https://elitedatascience.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/Pokemon.csv

I want to plot the heatmap as shown below:

```
# Calculate correlations
corr = stats_df.corr()
 
# Heatmap
plt.figure(figsize=(9,8))
sns.heatmap(corr)
```

But I get this error below; how can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: You want the correlation between what and what?

Comment: @Corralien I am trying to apply the example that is here (https://elitedatascience.com/python-seaborn-tutorial)

Comment: @Corralien If you saw the above link. It is working. I am trying to learn, dear sir.

Comment: That selects only the numeric columns. stats_df, in the example

Comment: As @TrentonMcKinney and I suggested, you need to select numeric columns to calculate this kind of correlation. That's why you have to select relevant columns before. I hope it's clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the (Pearson) correlation you need to have numeric data.

Try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Pokemon.csv', encoding='latin1', index_col='#')
corr = df.select_dtypes('number').drop(columns=['Total', 'Generation']).corr()
sns.heatmap(data=corr)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
>>> corr
               HP    Attack   Defense   Sp. Atk   Sp. Def     Speed
HP       1.000000  0.422386  0.239622  0.362380  0.378718  0.175952
Attack   0.422386  1.000000  0.438687  0.396362  0.263990  0.381240
Defense  0.239622  0.438687  1.000000  0.223549  0.510747  0.015227
Sp. Atk  0.362380  0.396362  0.223549  1.000000  0.506121  0.473018
Sp. Def  0.378718  0.263990  0.510747  0.506121  1.000000  0.259133
Speed    0.175952  0.381240  0.015227  0.473018  0.259133  1.000000
```

[image]

Comment: May I know where you get 'Generation' from? I applied your above solution, but it did not work for me, because it said ("['Generation'] not found in axis").

Comment: Remove 'Generation' from `drop` if it's not a part of your dataframe.